# Azure web app security: How to allow connections only from a whitelisted domains

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have one Azure webApp, I need to provide some security to that web app. I have below requirement.

1. Web app should not accept connection from all the domains. (It should have a list of domains from where it will accept connections)
2. If a new domain got added to whitelist domain, then my app will allow request from that new domain without restart or reconfigure.

Is there a way to configure at Azure level to allow requests  from specific domains.

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to work with a list of IPs instead of a list of domains?
If yes, Dynamic IP Address Restriction might help.

Please see:

http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#filtering-traffic-by-ip

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/StaticDynamic-IP-Restrictions-DDOS-Protection

https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: As this is cloud based web app, I don't have any information from where the call will come. I want to restrict my app to be accessible from our domains. So I don't have any consistent information about IP.

Comment: Your domains are corresponding to IPs (that's how DNS works). So instead of whitelist domains, why don't you whitelist the corresponding IPs?

Comment: I've added some references. If it helps, can you please validate the answer?

Comment: He specifically said based on domains not IPs